# PHP do include inherit namespace

Tags: php, namespaces

Assume the `index.php` looks like the below:

```
namespace testing;

include __DIR__ . 'anotherFile.php'
```

My question is do `anotherFile.php` inherit the namespace `namespace testing;`?

Comment: Sounds like the sort of thing you can easily test for yourself.

Comment: @RiggsFolly May I know how to test this?

Comment: Create a file called `index.php` with that content. Then create another file called `anotherFile.php` with a different namespace (or none) and see if you can access the things in the first namespace. Or just echo `__NAMESPACE__` from the second file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A php-file that is included with include or require does not inherit any namespace from the outside. If a namespace is defined in this file, then this applies. If no namespace is defined, the file works in the global namespace.